# Iphone programming- Importing an existing sql table to sqlite or core data

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite, core-data

I have a simple table that I'm pulling from our existing sql database. Its just a 1mb Vehicle table. It contains enough information that I don't want to create it from  scratch, but I can not find a definitive answer on how to import this table into my sqlite environment on the mac.

I've seen a few posts about python scripts that import to Core Data but I don't think thats the way to go.

The table I saved out as .rpt file. Any direction other than the one I'm traveling would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most correct (and pretty easy) way to do this is to write a little Mac OS X command line tool program that reads the data from your SQLite database and uses Core Data to load the data into a Core Data persistent store.

That persistent store -- the resulting Core Data schema'd SQLite file -- can be added as a resource to your iOS app project and it'll "just work".

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Christian Kienle's Core Data Editor, which let's you import data from CSV files into Core Data: http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor

It is also useful after the data is imported for debugging.